# Sending the email to the following server failed (apache commons - Java)

Tags: java, html, apache, email

I'm trying to send an HTML email using Apache Commons in my Java program. This is my code:

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
email.setHostName("mail.axc.nl");
email.setSslSmtpPort("465");
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
email.addTo(emailadr, name);
email.setFrom("noreply@smartfix.me", "SmartFix");
email.setSubject("Subject");
email.setHtmlMsg("here goes my message");
email.send();
```

Now, this works like a charm on my desktop computer (running Windows 8). Now, on my server (running Windows Server 2012), it fails. It always gets the following exception:

```
Sending the email to the following server failed: mail.axc.nl:465
```

I checked my credentials a dozen times, nothing wrong with them. I can't figure out why this wouldn't work on my Server, while it works perfectly fine on my desktop :S

**UPDATE: seems like the error occurs whenever you compile and run the program. When my code runs in netbeans, it works just fine. Here's the stack trace:**

```
C:\inetpub\tracking>java.exe -jar SmartFixGUI.jar
SmartFix Tracking Terminal - loaded successfully.
Currently tracking null
71QJD73I3I is a smartphone.
Currently tracking 71QJD73I3I
71QJD73I3I is a smartphone.
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following serve
r failed : mail.axc.nl:465
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
        at smartfixgui.trackingNumber.sendMail(trackingNumber.java:378)
        at smartfixgui.infoViewer.jButton2ActionPerformed(infoViewer.java:262)
        at smartfixgui.infoViewer.access$200(infoViewer.java:19)
        at smartfixgui.infoViewer$3.actionPerformed(infoViewer.java:149)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
        javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME ty
pe multipart/mixed;
        boundary="----=_Part_0_1999183509.1389954279345"
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1182)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME
 type multipart/mixed;
        boundary="----=_Part_0_1999183509.1389954279345"
        at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)
        at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1593)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1839)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1134)
        ... 44 more
```

**UPDATE 2: Seems like there might be a problem in my build.xml... When running the 'unpacked' version of the jar (my code in a jar, and apache/javax in a seperate jar's in a lib folder), everything works fine. When running the 'combined distribution' (apache, javax and my code packed in one jar), it goes wrong.**

Anyone spots an error in my build.xml? I've been using it for quite some time now, never had any problems :/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="SmartFixGUI" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project SmartFixGUI.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
<target name="-post-jar">
    <jar jarfile="dist/Combined-dist.jar">
    <zipfileset src="${dist.jar}" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="lib/commons-email-1.3.2.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="lib/javax.mail.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="smartfixgui.main"/>
    </manifest>
  </jar>
</target>
</project>
```

Comment: Can your server connect to `mail.axc.nl`? Is there a firewall?

Comment: Maybe there is any more meaningful information (like Connection Refused) in the stacktrace (especially in the lowest exception)?

Comment: For some reason, it seems like it's not working at all from the compiled jar file. It gets the exception on my desktop and on my server. But when I run it in netbeans, everything's working just fine. I'm adding the stack trace in a minute.

Comment: I think this is your problem: `UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed`

Comment: This problem can also occur because anti-virus software is blocking port 25.  Check your anti-virus log files for an entry like this: "7/10/2017 12:54:12 PM Blocked by port blocking rule  C:\PROGRAM FILES\JAVA\JRE1.8.0_131\BIN\JAVAW.EXE Anti-virus Standard Protection:Prevent mass mailing worms from sending mail 0:0:0:0:0:ffff:aa2:cdcc:25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gerald Schneider, I found a solution.

Googling a little further on the DCH exception, I found that adding this code before creating an Email object fixes it!

```
MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
```